# How to Fetch data to dynamically build out a custom Menu for a Layout?

Tags: react-admin

What I would like to do is, call an endpoint to get the list of categories to display in the Sidebar's Menu. I'm not seeing anything in the Layout that would handle this.  Am I missing something?  What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: React-admin doesn't provide anything special for that purpose, so you can just use pure React for your Menu.

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto thanks.  Could you comment on this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218084/how-to-embed-one-react-admin-component-inside-another-multiple-admin-components

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @François, good to know I don't need to look any further in the Layout or Menu files.

Looking at the Demo source code, I see this approach in action using Reacts `useState` and `useEffect`.

Posted for others, this is in my Admin component:

```
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState({categories: []});
useEffect(
    () => {
        dataProvider.getList('tools', {
            sort: '',
            pagination: {
                page: 1,
                perPage: 10
            }
        }).then(data =>
            setCategories({categories: data['data']}))
    },
    []
);
```