# How to embed one React-Admin component inside another; multiple Admin components

Tags: react-admin

Is this possible?
I'd like to use one `<Admin` to display other imported `<Admin` components.  I'm hoping to do something like this where `MyTool` is an imported `<Admin` component:

```
    <Admin layout={MyLayout}
           dataProvider={myDataProvider}
           customRoutes={[
               <Route
                   exact
                   path="/tools"
                   component={(props) => <MyTool {...props} />}/>

           ]}>
    </Admin>
```

Comment: react-admin maintainer here: this has never been a requirement of react-admin, and I've never tested it. It probably won't work, and I personally think it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try wrapping each `<Admin` in my own Provider without any success so I'm considering Francois Z. answer to be definitive.

`react-admin maintainer here: this has never been a requirement of react-admin, and I've never tested it. It probably won't work, and I personally think it's a bad idea. – François Zaninotto 5 hours ago`